# queryFn is not being called when useQuery contains initialData (react-query)

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm using react query, suppose I have to use some default data. Whenever I have the 'initialData', the queryFn is not being called, hence onSucess is not being called as well. So, the data of that useQuery is still the same of the 'initialData' I have implemented.

```
   const getProducts = () => {
    console.log("from getProducts");
    //Fetch data
    }

    export const useProducts = () =>
        useQuery({
            queryKey: ["AllProducts"],
            cacheTime: Infinity,
            staleTime: Infinity,
            initialData: {
                products: [],
            },
            queryFn: () => getProducts(),
            onSuccess: (data) => {
                console.log("from onSuccess");
                // Do some stuff
            }
```

The weird is neither **console.log("from getProducts");** nor **console.log("from onSuccess");** are being called. I know that I can use 'placeholder' instead of 'initialData'. But the question is why does this happen?

Note that these are the versions of react-query and react-query dev tools:

```
"@tanstack/react-query": "^4.29.12",
"@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.29.12",
```

I have used 'placeholder' instead of 'initialData' and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the desired behaviour of `initialData` if you combine it with `staleTime`. `initialData` is persisted to the cache, and query doesn't care how data goes into the cache - once it's there, `staleTime` is respected. Since yours is `Infinity`, the query cache is like: "I have data cached that never gets stale, so I don't need to run the queryFn to revalidate, ever".

If you want a refetch, as you said, `placeholderData` is your friend. I've written about the differences here: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/placeholder-and-initial-data-in-react-query